# Access components of a list of data frames for use in loops in R

Tags: r, list, for-loop, dataframe

I want to write code that will create separate hour and minute columns in each of 13 data frames that contain a column named "DateTimeDur" . As I will likely need to perform other operations on each of these data sets in the future, I would like to establish an easy block of code that will perform any operation on *each* set. Specifically, I need to get a for loop to add columns to each set.

First, I put all my data sets in dflist, then I set about making a for loop where time in the form "hh:mm:ss *other nonsense*" produces a column for hours and another column for minutes. This works if I do it on any one data set, but I can't get it to work in for loop for all data sets in dflist. It doesn't produce any errors - just fails to add "hour" and "minute" columns to each one like I expect...

```
dflist <- c(FAT1, FAT2, FAT3, FAT4, FAT5, FAT6, FAT7, FAT8, FAT9, FAT10, FAT11, FAT12, FAT13)

    Time <- Time2 <- TimeMin <- vector("list", length(FAT1$RecNumber))
    for(i in dflist){
      Time  <- factor(i["TimeDateDura"])
      Time2 <- strptime(Time, "%H:%M:%S")
      TimeHr <- format(Time2, "%H")
      TimeMin <- format(Time2, "%M")
      i["hour"] <- TimeHr
      i["min"] <- TimeMin
    }
```

A typical data set (FAT1, etc.) looks like this:

```
RecNumber Label  Fat  Lean FreeWater TotalWater  TimeDateDura Accumulation Weight Comments
1         87001 1.47 11.19      0.05       9.46  09:31:02 Jan 30, 2018; 78;            1      0       NA
2         87002 1.46 11.39      0.07      10.07  09:33:10 Jan 30, 2018; 79;            1      0       NA
3         87003 1.13 10.43      0.15       9.23  09:35:21 Jan 30, 2018; 101;           1      0       NA
```

Answer (score 0):

In what follows I will use CRAN package [lubridate](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/index.html), since it makes it much easier to work with dates and times.

```
library(lubridate)

dflist <- lapply(dflist, function(DF){
  tmp <- hms(DF[["TimeDateDura"]])
  DF[["hour"]] <- hour(tmp)
  DF[["min"]] <- minute(tmp)
  DF
})

dflist$FAT1
#$FAT1
#   TimeDateDura hour min
#1      01:12:57    1  12
#2      04:10:12    4  10
#3      06:41:39    6  41
#4      08:23:07    8  23
#5      13:46:16   13  46
#6      15:30:23   15  30
#7      15:43:00   15  43
#8      21:60:23   21  60
#9      21:23:53   21  23
#10     22:47:20   22  47
```

**Data creation code.**

```
set.seed(1)

dflist <- lapply(1:13, function(i){
  h <- sort(sprintf("%02d", sample(0:23, 10, TRUE)))
  m <- sprintf("%02d", sample(0:60, 10, TRUE))
  s <- sprintf("%02d", sample(0:60, 10, TRUE))
  data.frame(TimeDateDura = paste(h, m, s, sep = ":"))
})
names(dflist) <- paste0("FAT", 1:13)
```